# Simple HXR request return mysql response

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to get my head around asynchronous interactions between client and server once and for all! I keep stumbling over this problem and I need to understand it.

Here is my stumbling block:

I have a simple nodeJS file that should listen on port 8080 and respond with the results from a mysql query. here it is:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const http = require('http');
const Promise = require('promise');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "user",
  password: "password",
  database: "database"
});

const queryDatabase = (query = "SELECT * FROM users") => new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    con.connect( (err) => {
      if (err) throw(err);
      else {
        con.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
          if (err) throw(err);
          resolve(JSON.stringify(result));
        })
      }
    })
  } catch(err) {
    reject(err);
  }
})

http.createServer( async (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  // res.write(req.url);
  res.write('here are your results: ', await queryDatabase());
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

When I run this file and point my browser to it i get the message "here are your results: " but with no results.

I know this is a really simple problem that I am going to meet over and over again.

If anyone could provide a simple example of this code working and maybe point me towards some pertinent reading I would be incredibly grateful.

Thanks,

Dan.

Answer (score 0):

See https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback.

The signature is:

```
response.write(chunk[, encoding][, callback])
```

It seems you are using the result of the query as the `encoding` instead of the `chunk`. Try something like:

```
res.write('here are your results: ' + await queryDatabase());
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I have tried your suggestion and it didn't change the outcome. I'm not getting any errors either in the console (my bash terminal) or the browser. I think the problem is to do with synchronicity I.E. the result from queryDatabase() is being resolved after the response is returned to the browser.